How to Pull Just Date rather than DateTime for Query on Razor Page
I have a report that the user only wants to enter a data and have all records that have that date appear on the report. Currently, the report is set to a range where the user enters a starting date and time and an ending date and time. Since she says they only ever need one day at a time and all times for that day, she would prefer to only enter a single date to save time.
My question is how to I do that in my query? I'm just not sure of the syntax. The data records are stored as DateTime, so I'm thinking of some sort of substring to grab just the date, but again, not sure of syntax.
Here is a snippet from my working query on the .cs page as it is now, pulling a range of dates and times:
public Trip Trip { get; set; }
public Client Client { get; set; }
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

public PaginatedList<ReportModel> ScheduledTrips { get; set; } = default!; 

public async Task OnGet(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, int? pageIndex)
{
    StartDate = startDate;
    EndDate = endDate;

    IQueryable<ReportModel> scheduledTrips = from x in _context.Trip
                                            join y in _context.Client on x.ClientName equals y.DisplayName
                                            where x.PickUpDateTime >= startDate && x.PickUpDateTime <= endDate
                                            orderby x.PickUpDateTime
                                             select new ReportModel

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Add a property named ReportDate and enable it to be bound during GET requests. Set its datatype to Date, which will ensure the browser date picker doesn't include the time portion when you use the input tag helper.
<input asp-for="ReportDate" />

In the query, set the date range to be selected by adding a day to the ReportDate, so the query for today, for example, will range from 2024-6-6 00:00:00 to 2024-6-7 00:00:00. In other words, all records with today's date.
public Trip Trip { get; set; }
public Client Client { get; set; }
[BindProperty(SupportsGet=true), DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime ReportDate { get; set; }


public PaginatedList<ReportModel> ScheduledTrips { get; set; } = default!; 

public async Task OnGet(int? pageIndex)
{
    var from = ReportDate;
    var to = ReportDate.AddDays(1);
    IQueryable<ReportModel> scheduledTrips = from x in _context.Trip
                                            join y in _context.Client on x.ClientName equals y.DisplayName
                                            where x.PickUpDateTime >= from && x.PickUpDateTime <= to
                                            orderby x.PickUpDateTime
                                             select new ReportModel

Check working with dates and times here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/dates-and-times

Hi Mike, thanks so much for the reply. Your explanation makes perfect sense to me, however, when I apply it I am getting a CS1061 error: DateTime does not contain a definition for 'AddDays'... and the AddDays is underlined. It also says that the && in the query itself is an 'invalid expression term' tho it is the from that is underlined, not the &&. Ideas? I think I have the changes done correctly. I noted that the ending ] was missing above so added it at the end of the Bind Property line.

OK had the DateTime nullable - Removed the ? and now I am down to just the && being invalid.

Got it working. I had to add another "inbetween variable". Not quite understanding that, but by adding var v = from; and then replacing from with v in the query where clause, it worked!

Sorry for any typos and glad you got it working
